# Why have the X server configuration files moved from /etc/Xorg to /usr/share/Xorg?

Tags: xorg, lsb

It used to be the case (since the XFree86 days and maybe earlier) that X server configuration files are to be found under `/etc`; namely in `/etc/Xorg`. However, recent distributions (at least, recent Arch and Debian) put it under `/usr/share/X11`. Why is that? Doesn't host-level configuration belong under `/etc` ?

Answer (score 1):

From `man 5 xorg.conf`, after describing a whole lot of locations under `/etc`:

```
   Finally, configuration files will also be searched for in  a  directory
   reserved  for system use.  This is to separate configuration files from
   the vendor or 3rd party packages from those  of  local  administration.
   These files are found in the following directory:

       /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

So if you want to make a local adjustment, copy a file from `/usr/share/X11` to its appropriate place under `/etc`. If these files would be updated from your vendor, your local, system wide configuration will not be overridden.

Comment: So, you're saying `/usr/share/X11` are package defaults while `/etc/X11/` are local modifications? Also - why is this now the case when previously it wasn't? And considering the fact this convention is not very popular with other packages, which simply install their default settings under `/etc` and let you modify them?

Comment: @einpoklum It's an improvement. Instead of local settings being drowned in thousands of lines of boilerplate, the default settings go to `/usr` and the local overrides go to `/etc`. It's actually the way it should be, and many packages do follow this convention — maybe you didn't notice because you never went to look for configuration files and libraries under `/usr`.